# How can i get the count of JSON keys present under the array?

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON as shown below

```
var result = [
    {
        "SurCharges": "50"
    },
    {
        "SurCharges": "50"
    },
    {
        "SurCharges": "50"
    }
]
```

As there are 3 elements present inside the result array

How can i get its length ??

I have tried it this way

But it isn't working

could anybody please help

```
alert(result[0].length);
```

Comment: What about result.length?

Comment: `result.length` or `Object.keys(result[0]).length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.lenght`

```
var numberOfElements = result.length;
alert (numberOfElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
alert(result.length);
```